How to convert this Excel formula to snowflake query?
I have this below Excel formula and need to duplicate it in Snowflake query.
In column E
=If(B2=B1,E1-D2,C2-D2)

I used this below query.
 SELECT 
 THEATER, PARTS, Open_Repair_Orders,Non_Restricted_Empty_Bins,
 case when 
 parts = lag(parts) over (order by parts) 
 then (lag(non_restricted_empty_bins,1,0) over (partition by parts order by theater) - non_restricted_empty_bins)
 else Open_Repair_Orders - Non_Restricted_Empty_Bins end as Rpr_Order_Consumption
 FROM CX_DB.CX_GSLOBAC_STG.XXBAC_SPM_FILL_RATE_TEST;

My input is from column A to D and Column E is my desired output.



THEATER
PARTS
Open_Repair_Orders
Non_Restricted_Empty_Bins
Rpr_Order_Consumption




EMEA
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


NAM
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


EMEA
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


LAM
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


EMEA
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


EMEA
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


LAM
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
1
10


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
10


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
10


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
10


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11



But I'm getting 0s as result after 11 in Rpr_Order_Consumption.
Can someone please help me with this problem. I can share any additional information.
Thanks in advance.
I tried with the below snowflake query.
    SELECT 
    THEATER, PARTS, Open_Repair_Orders,Non_Restricted_Empty_Bins,
    case when 
        parts = lag(parts) over (order by parts) 
            then (lag(non_restricted_empty_bins,1,0) over (partition by parts order by theater) - non_restricted_empty_bins)
    else Open_Repair_Orders - Non_Restricted_Empty_Bins end as Rpr_Order_Consumption
    FROM CX_DB.CX_GSLOBAC_STG.XXBAC_SPM_FILL_RATE_TEST;

Column E is my desired output.



THEATER
PARTS
Open_Repair_Orders
Non_Restricted_Empty_Bins
Rpr_Order_Consumption




EMEA
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


NAM
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


EMEA
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


LAM
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


EMEA
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


EMEA
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


LAM
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
1
10


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
10


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
10


APAC
Z4-HW-NB & Rpr
11
0
10


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11


APAC
Z4-HW-NB
11
0
11




Lets start with example data that "makes sense" and that requires accepts there is no such thing as a row number in SQL, so lets enrich the data so it appears like in Excel:
select * from values
(1,'EMEA', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(2,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(3,'NAM ', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(4,'EMEA', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(5,'LAM ', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(6,'EMEA', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(7,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(8,'EMEA', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(9,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(10,'LAM ', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(11,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(12,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(13,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(14,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(15,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
(16,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 1, 10),
(17,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 10),
(18,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 10),
(19,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 10),
(20,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB', 11, 0, 11),
(21,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB', 11, 0, 11),
(22,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB', 11, 0, 11),
(23,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB', 11, 0, 11),
(24,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB', 11, 0, 11),
(25,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB', 11, 0, 11),
(26,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB', 11, 0, 11),
(27,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB', 11, 0, 11)
as t(n, A, B, C, D, E);

now we can push that into a CTE and select it:
with example_data as (
    select * from values
        (1,'EMEA', 'Z4-HW-NB & Rpr', 11, 0, 11),
-- trimmed for visuals
        (27,'APAC', 'Z4-HW-NB', 11, 0, 11)
        as t(n, A, B, C, D, E)
)
select a,b,c,d,e
from example_data

lovely. next, Snowflake has IFF which is the same as Excel IF
thus
select a,b,c,d,e
    -- =If(B2=B1,E1-D2,C2-D2)
    ,lag(b)over(order by n) as l_b
    ,lag(e)over(order by n) as l_e
    ,iff(b=l_b, l_e-d, c-d) as result
from example_data
order by n

gives:

thus could be:
select a,b,c,d,e
    ,iff(b=lag(b)over(order by n), lag(e)over(order by n)-d, c-d) as result
from example_data
order by n

